# Rails cache & ActiveRecord eager fetching - Fetch only if the fragment hasn't been cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a controller method which currently looks like:

```
@people = Person.where(conditions).includes(eager_fetch).all
```

I'm now trying to make the controller cache-aware. Since the eager fetch is rather expensive, I want to avoid loading as much data as possible. If it's relevant, the output is XML from an RPC style endpoint. I've arrived at:

```
@people = Person.where(conditions).all
@fragments = {}
@people.dup.each do |person|
  cache_key = "fragment-for-#{person.id}-#{person.updated_at.to_i}"
  fragment = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key)
  unless fragment.nil?
    @fragments[person.id] = fragment
    @people.delete person
  end
end
@people = Person.where(:id => @people.collect(&:id)).includes(eager_fetch).all
```

There's another possibility, which is very much the same, except instead of re-querying on the last line,

```
Person.send :preload_associations, @people, eager_fetch
```

Am I missing an important piece of API for handling this correctly? Currently on Rails 3.0.12, but will be upgrading to 3.2.x, so a solution that only works with 3.2.x would be fine. Neither of my solutions seem elegant to me.

*(I've anonymized and simplified this code, apologies if I've left out anything important)*

Comment: Just a tip: you shouldn't need to call `.all` at the end of your active record method chaining. By default it fetches all the records that match.

Comment: @gylaz: I like to make my `.all` explicit. Partly to remove ambiguity around where the data is loaded, and partly because for every SQL query I track the line of code it originated from, for debugging and optimization purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Don't rely on ActiveRecord's eager loading. It will load everything that isn't in the ActiveRecord per-request query cache.

Instead query for your primary object, and then use your own crafty method to fetch the cached things and query the slower datastore for the missed ID's.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that would be a problem, when I know for a fact I'm only loading the objects that I need, and they're only being retrieved once?